# How can I tell what version my SSL supports?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have a security requirement checklist that requires the following:

> SSL must be configured to support only SSL version 3 or TLS version

How can I tell what version my SSL supports? I'm using openssl.

Comment: SSL certificates don't support versions at all, although they have versions internally, which is not what your requirement is about. Do you mean what version(s) your SSL *software* supports?

Comment: @EJP The requirement is pretty vague, so now that you mention it, it makes more sense that they mean software. I just changed the title to reflect your advice.

Comment: What do you call "an SSL"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing software using OpenSSL the choice of what particular instance of the protocol (SSL2, SSL3, TLS1) is permitted is established by the context that you make for creating SSL objects.  Here is the minimal example of setting up a context that supports only TLS1:

new_ctx = SSL_CTX_new (TLSv1_server_method ());

If you want to support SSL3 and above, you'd use:

new_ctx = SSL_CTX_new (SSLv23_method ());

SSL_CTX_set_options (new_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);

This only scratches the surface, but maybe will point you in the right direction.